# Cultureinfo: how to get only languagecode

Tags: windows-phone-7, globalization, cultureinfo, currentculture

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

How can I get the language code from CultureInfo.CurrentCulture?

I'm using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name and I getting 'en-US'. I only need en.

Comment: Part 35 - Windows Phone 7 - Culure http://dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=163

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`TwoLetterISOLanguageName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.twoletterisolanguagename.aspx) property?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. If all you want is to remove the region, retaining the script distinction (if you are interested in zh-Hans for example and not just zh) then you will want to use the [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent.aspx) property (). Though this can return legacy (zh-CHS) so you would want to use the [IetfLanguageTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.ietflanguagetag.aspx) property to resolve that:

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Parent.IetfLanguageTag

```
en-US -> en
zh-CN -> zh-Hans
zh-TW -> zh-Hant
```

Sometimes it still isn't going to give you the expected answer since it will only language tags that are supported (but this isn't any different from the TwoLetterISOLanguageName property):

```
az-Cyrl-AZ -> az
az-Latn-AZ -> az
```

And it seems like some of the chains were omitted:

```
sr-Cyrl-BA -> (Invariant)
```

You can check for invariant and then return the TwoLetterISOLanguageName property to work around that.

Comment: I realize this is an older answer. However, for people viewing this answer now: In VS 2013 and .NET 4.5, it appears that `leftLanguageTag` is deprecated.